# Override DenyGroups in sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh

I have an `sshd_config` file that is configured not to allow users in the group `nologin` to `ssh` in to this server (`DenyGroups nologin`).  While I have several users in this group, I do want to override this for one of the users (let's call the user `greg`).

I tried adding `AllowUsers greg` to the `sshd_config` file, but that didn't seem to work. Is it possible to do this?

The sshd_config looks like:

```
   AllowTcpForwarding no
   ClientAliveCountMax 1
   ClientAliveInterval 300
   LoginGraceTime 1m
   PermitRootLogin no
   Protocol 2 
   RSAAuthentication no
   Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
   UsePAM yes
   X11Forwarding yes
   DenyGroups nologin
   LogLevel INFO
   MaxAuthTries 4
   IgnoreRhosts yes
   HostBasedAuthentication no
   PermitEmptyPasswords no
   PermitUserEnvironment no
   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
```

Adding "AllowUsers greg" (greg is a member of the login group) does not allow greg to ssh.

Comment: maybe additional question would be what version of openssh are you using. The behaviour can be changed. My answer refers to current version (7.1).

Answer (score 2):

Manual page for `sshd_config(5)` describes the behaviour of these options like this:

> If specified, *login is allowed/disallowed only for users/groups whose primary group or supplementary group list or name matches one of the patterns.* Only group names are valid; a numerical group ID is not recognized.  By default, login is allowed for all groups. The allow/deny directives are processed in the following order: **DenyUsers**, **AllowUsers**, **DenyGroups**, and finally **AllowGroups**.

This hints that if you define only these two options, it *should* work for you. You probably use some other options which interfere with your setup. Can you post the whole config you are using?

Comment: See edit in original post

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that this way, since **all** directives are evaluated before `sshd` makes a final decision. Thus, although `greg` is allowed by `AllowUsers`, it's denied later on by the `DenyGroups` matching the group he is in. The manual is somewhat unspecific here, because it does not mention that all directives are evaluated in the order described by Jakuje, so I tried this in OpenSSH 5.2p1 on a spare system. Indeed, the evaluation order should be the other way around (first allow/deny groups, next allow/deny users). That would make much more sense, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems straight forward to me, just remove `greg` from the `nologin` group.